# Trying to include https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js locally but I get a Facebook Pixel Error

Tags: javascript, facebook

In firefox I get

```
Facebook Pixel Error: TypeError: cd is undefined
```

Chrome

```
Facebook Pixel Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

The html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0]}(window,document,'script','//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
fbq("init","1111111111111111");fbq("track","PageView");
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/fbevents.js" async="async"></script>
```

Contents of /js/fbevents.js is the same as https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js. Any idea why these error are showing up?

The inline script has been modified and `s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)` has been removed from this example https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-websites/pixel-events/v2.10

Looks like its trying to load and failing...
https://connect.facebook.net/signals/config/1111111111111111?v=2.7.19 which is triggered by this JS at the bottom of fbevents.js

```
fbq.registerPlugin("global_config", {
__fbEventsPlugin: 1,
plugin: function(fbq, instance) {
    fbq.loadPlugin("opttracking");
    fbq.loadPlugin("performance");
    instance.configLoaded("global_config");
}
});
```

Note 1111111111111111 is not the real PIXEL_ID. The real PIXEL_ID returns legit JS.

Comment: In order to get around the 1 week browser cache negative hit from Google PageSpeed https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/LeverageBrowserCaching

Answer (score 0):

Modifying fbevents.js to give ac and bc smart defaults if the wb regex fails fixes the issue.

```
function xb() {
    var ac = 'https://connect.facebook.net',
        cc = rb.getElementsByTagName('script'),
        bc = cc[0];
    for (var dc = 0; dc < cc.length && !ac; dc++) {
        var ec = cc[dc].src.split(wb);
        if (ec.length > 1) {
            ac = ec[0];
            bc = cc[dc];
        }
    }
    return {
        baseURL: ac,
        scriptElement: bc
    };
}
```

before

```
function xb() {
    var ac = null,
        bc = null,
        cc = rb.getElementsByTagName('script');
    for (var dc = 0; dc < cc.length && !ac; dc++) {
        var ec = cc[dc].src.split(wb);
        if (ec.length > 1) {
            ac = ec[0];
            bc = cc[dc];
        }
    }
    return {
        baseURL: ac,
        scriptElement: bc
    };
}
```